# Capybara: is it possible to tag `@javascript` only one step in a scenario? Not the whole scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, capybara-webkit

The example from Capybara documentation. They tag the whole scenario:

```
You can switch to the Capybara.javascript_driver (:selenium by default) by tagging scenarios (or features) with @javascript:

@javascript
Scenario: do something Ajaxy
  When I click the Ajax link
  ...
```

But I want to tag only one step:

```
Background:
    Given I am on the homepage
    And There is a button "Click me"
    When I click the button "Click me"
    @javascript
    Then I should see a js pop-up element "Hello" within "#hello .hello"
```

Is it acceptable behavior? Or do I need to create a separate `@javascript` tagged Scenario for only this click action?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no.
I got `Gherkin::Parser::ParseError`:

```
../features/deleting_tickets.feature: Parse error at ../features/deleting_tickets.feature:17. 

Found step when expecting one of: examples, feature, scenario, scenario_outline, tag.
(Current state: tag). (Gherkin::Parser::ParseError)
```

So one more disadvantage met.